# How to import modules to threejs project correctly?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to import modules so I can use the bloom effect, but I keep getting this error.
The .js were copied from *three/examples/js/* so they are up to date.

**index.html:**

```
<script src="../module/three.js";></script>
<script src="../module/EffectComposer.js"></script>
<script src="../module/CopyShader.js"></script>
<script src="../module/ShaderPass.js"></script>
<script src="../module/RenderPass.js"></script>
<script src="../module/UnrealBloomPass.js"></script>
<script src="../module/MaskPass.js"></script>
<script src="../module/Pass.js"></script>
<script src="../module/LuminosityHighPassShader.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

**index.js:**

```
import * as THREE from "../module/three.module.js";

...
//bloom renderer
const renderScene = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);
```

and it results in the following error:
***Uncaught TypeError: THREE.RenderPass is not a constructor***

How am I supposed to do it in the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing `three.js` twice. One time via script tag and another time via ES6 import statement. This is a wrong pattern and definitely needs to be prevented.

The ES6 import redefines the `THREE` namespace in your app and thus overwrites the previous imports via the `script` tag. So please delete the following line and try it again:

```js
import * as THREE from "../module/three.module.js";
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. Though I wonder now why I had to import three.module in the first place, what is the difference between three.js and three.module.js?

Comment: It's UMD vs. ESM. I suggest you google the topic. There are a lot of related resources.